# PhpStorm - Method not found for object which is array element

Tags: phpstorm

I know that for variables which aren't declared as types PhpStorm doesn't know where to look for method calls on variable names sometimes.

I know how to solve it for simple variable by providing typehint via simple PHPDoc comment :

```
/* @var Category $category */
$category->getNameTranslit();
```

but how can I do this for methods called for array element?

```
$categories[$key]->setIsActive(true);
```

Comment: **1)** *(a bit off topic)* You are not using PHPDoc -- it's an ordinary comment that IDE interprets the same as PHPDoc. PHPDoc comments start with `/**` (2 asterisk symbols) **2)** Let me clarify this first -- so `$categories` is an array of `Category` instances -- right? If so -- `/** @var Category[] $categories */` **3)** *(general note, since I do not know how the rest of the code looks -- it may be all fine from your end)* Try providing correct `@return` tag for functions as well as typehinting fields via `@var` -- this way local vars have bigger changes of being auto-deducted correctly.

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks! works fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appeared to be:

```
 /** @var Category[] $categories */
 $categories[$key]->setIsActive(true);
```

Thank you LazyOne!